# Unresolved references for Kotlin (JVM) Standard Library Elements

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm, kotlin

After adding `gradle` to an existing Kotlin project in `IntelliJ`, I started having issues with references to some standard library elements. For instance, Kotlin `String` type is recognized, but the `mutableMapOf` is giving me

```
 Error:(11, 60) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: mutableMapOf
```

another is:

```
Error:(9, 78) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Array
```

during compilation. They are marked red in the IDE, as well (not isolated to only compilation)

Another error that appears in `IntelliJ` is `Kotlin not configured`, with no options to configure `Kotlin`

Here is my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

group = "com.serguei.myproject"
version = "1.0"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have to tried remove this project in IntelliJ and re-import it with gradle?

Comment: I have tried and unfortunately I am still having the same issue. Thank you for the suggestion @ice1000

Comment: I've experienced the same issue: did you remove the project, clean all build folders, and re-import and refresh? Try force refreshing dependencies before building by running `gradle --refresh-dependencies ...`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments Ice100 and Preston Garno, they have helped greatly in finding a solution.

The issue was that my project was not structured correctly. I had:

```
MyProject -> src -> [Source Files]
          -> build.gradle
```

however, after consulting [Using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) more closely, it appears that the recommended project structure should be

```
MyProject -> src -> main -> kotlin -> [Source Files]
          -> build.gradle
```

Once the project structure is adjusted, go into `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and click the `Invalidate and Restart`. Once the indexer is rerun, the `Kotlin` standard library types, functions, etc. should now be available.

Answer (score 0):

For any one coming to this page because of problem that IntelliJ suddenly does not find stuff in kotlin standard library: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` helped me in a situation which didn't even involve gradle.

Answer (score 0):

After migrating my Java app to Kotlin I find myself in this situation.

After checking gradle structure [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)
You can sync your project with gradle using sync button from menu bar.
this will download necessary files for Kotlin

Then you can just validate cache & Restart if necessary.